# has_one not updating attribute id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have a DB relationship where a User has a PreferenceList. I have set up a preference_list_id in the database table, and I have set up a `belongs_to :user` relationship with PreferenceList and a `has_one :preference_list` relationship with User.

Here's the weird part. If I do `user.preference_list = preference_list`, I can access user.preference_list and it will give me the correct instance of preference_list. However, if I do user.preference_list_id (a valid, column, I've checked), it gives me nothing even after I have added preference_list to user.preference_list. I need the id to be updated for various database operations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you saving the user after adding the preference list?

Comment: Yes. I've tried calling user.save and user.reload to no avail.

Comment: look in the logs. it should show the associated object being saved, unless there is some sort of validation failure?

Answer (score 2):

The foreign key goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association. So if you have

```
class PreferenceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :preference_list
end
```

table `preferences_lists` should have `user_id` columns. Rails will handle this columns properly. You can add `preference_list_id` column to `users` table as well. But this column has no special meaning, Rails will do nothing with it by default. Try to change belongs_to/has_one sides if you really need to operate `preference_list_id`. Or use `user.preference_list.id`